# How to put data i read from file to hashmap <String, Set<String>>?

Tags: java, dictionary

I need to store data from file i have read, the data structure is: ip adress and id (1.10.186.214;2812432), and  id can have multiple ip.

here is the code i use to read file. I use Treemap userdb to store information about users. Also i need another map to store id and ip.

```
File file = new File(path);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        Map<String, User> userdb = new TreeMap<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String ip = line.split(";")[0];
            String id = line.split(";")[1];
            String fio = line.split(";")[2];
            String adress = line.split(";")[3];
            User user = new User(id, fio, adress);
            userdb.put(id, user);
        }
        scanner.close();
```

I have decided to use Hashmap  id as key and set of ip as value. Is this the right way?  And if it is not, what are the other options?

Comment: You are splitting each line into 4 components but your example only has two (the IP address and the user ID).  What are the other 2 for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the `User` that the IP address belongs to I would suggest you use that as the key for your second data structure:

```
Map<User, Set<InetAddress>> mappings = new HashMap<>();
```

(I have used `InetAddress` here but you may already have a class for this?)

You can then look up or create the set of IP addresses for a given user and add the new entry:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
mappings.computeIfAbsent(user, ignored -> new HashSet<>()).add(address);
```

Your code has a couple of other possible issues:

1. You are splitting each line into four components but your example data only has two?
2. You create a *new* user for every entry when you have stated that a user can have multiple IP addresses (which is the point of the second data structure). You want to check whether you already have the user in `userdb` first, i.e:

```
        final User user;
        if(users.containsKey(id)) {
            user = users.get(id);
        }
        else {
            user = new User(id);
            users.put(id, user);
        }
```

(You could use the `computeIfAbsent` approach again here to simply the logic).

Your `User` class should correctly implement `hashCode` and `equals` if you decide to use it as the key. Alternative #1 just the user ID as the key. Alternative #2 move the `Set<InetAddress>` into the `User` class where it logically lives anyway.

Finally there's not much point splitting the line four times, it won't matter for this exercise I imagine but it's a good habit to get into: `final String[] parts = line.split(";"); String ip = parts[0]; ...`